# How to fill with colour like the fill in the paint?

Tags: javafx, colors, fill

I am trying to do the paint on Javafx. I am using a pane and draw an irregular shape using the code below (like using the pencil in the Microsoft Paint). Then I wished to colour the shape. I have no idea how to fill the colour.

The following code is how I draw on the pane.

```
@FXML
private void drawingAreaMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
    if(e.getX() > 0 && e.getY() > 0) {
        if(isPen) {
        if(e.getX() > penSize && e.getY() > penSize) {
        Circle newCircle = new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), penSize, pForeColor);
        group.getChildren().add(newCircle);
        }
    }
}
```

What I expecting is something like the following pictures (like the Microsoft Paint). First, draw using pencil and form the irregular shape. Then fill it.

[new pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e80Py.png)

[shape drawn using pencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNru7.png)

[fill with colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8btTW.png)

Comment: If you were using a `Canvas` I'd say use a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Since you're using shapes, however, you can simply change the `fill` of the `Shape` when it's clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for replying! It is my mistake that I didn't state clearly, I am using a pane and draw an irregular shape using the code above (like using the pencil in the Microsoft Paint). Then I wished to colour the shape. Is that a way to make it?

Comment: Maybe add your points to  a `Polygon` or `Polyline`?